# rendering component, after another distant component renders

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

In *navigation menu app*, down the component tree, there is a dropdown menu component `DropdownMenu2`, with menu items, which are `<NavLinks>` components. Every time an item is clicked, it points to one of the `<Route>`s in main `App`. Every `<Route>` is a page, containing `Infofield` component. So every time `<NavLink>` is clicked, `Infofield` is rendered.

My puzzle is: I need the `HeaderLogo` component be rendered, everytime `Infofield` is rendered (`HeaderLogo` contains animation). I failed when constructing `useEffect` hook in `Infofield`. That hook was intended to contain custom hook, producing a variable with changing state. That hook could be then lifted up to `App`, from there variable would be passed to `HeaderLogo`, inline to the `key` property. If that idea is legit, I'm experiencing difficulties with construction of custom hook inside of `useEffect`. Maybe (probably) there is a better way...

---

Apps most basic structure looks like this:

**App**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import HeaderLogo from "./components/HeaderLogo";
import NaviMain from "./components/NaviMain";
import Info from "./pages/Info";
/...
import { UserContext } from "./components/sub-components/UserContext";
   
function App() {
    
  return (
    <Router>
        <div className="App">
          
            <HeaderLogo />
            <NaviMain  />

          <Routes>
             <Route path="/Info" element={<Info />} />
             /...           
          </Routes>
          
        </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**NaviMain**

```
import "./NaviMain.css";
import NaviMainButton from "./NaviMainButton";
import NaviMainButtonDrop2 from "./NaviMainButtonDrop";

const NaviMain = () => {

  return (

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <NaviMainButtonDrop2 />
            </ul>
      </nav>  
  )
}
export default NaviMain
```

**NaviMainButtonDrop2**

```
import DropdownMenu2 from "./DropdownMenu2";

const NaviMainButtonDrop2 = () => {
  
  return (
    <li>
        <a>
           title
        </a>
        <DropdownMenu2 /> 
    </li>
  )
}
export default NaviMainButtonDrop2
```

**DropdownMenu2**

```
import "./DropdownMenu.css"
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { MenuItemContentSchool } from "./sub-components/MenuItemContentSchool"

const DropdownMenu2 = () => {
    
  return (
    <div className=dropdown-holder-us>
      {/* here menu unfolds */}
    {MenuItemContentSchool.map((item) => {
      return (
        <NavLink
            to={item.link} 
            className={(navData) => (navData.isActive ? "d-content-us active-style" : 'd-content-us')} 
            key={item.id} 
        >
          {item.title}
        </NavLink> 
      )
    })}
    </div>
  )
}
export default DropdownMenu2
```

**Info** (one of the `<Route>`'s )

```
import InfoField from "../components/InfoField"


const Info = () => {
  return (
    <section className="intro-index">
      <InfoField text={"welcome"} />
    </section>
  )
}
export default Info
```

**HeaderLogo**

```
import "./HeaderLogo.css";

const HeaderLogo = () => {

  return (
    <header>
        <h1 className="head-main">learning curve</h1>
    </header>
  )
}
export default HeaderLogo
```

Comment: It is unclear what your question is, if there is one. It's unclear what the issue is. It's unclear what you are trying to accomplish. Are you just wanting to render the `HeaderLogo` component only on certain routes?

Comment: I want to synchronize `HeaderLogo` with `Infofield`, in a specific way: every time  `Infofield` renders, that triggers `HeaderLogo` to render as well. Purpose: `Infofield` holds animation, which is triggered after component re-render.  What I'm trying to achieve cant be found in vanilla JS version of the website: [code-learning.uk](http://www.code-learning.uk) ("learning curve" logo behavior)

Comment: I don't understand what you want us to understand what you want *your* code to do from that other page, especially since it doesn't appear to animate anything other than a React logo at the bottom of the page. It basically sounds like you just want to run *some* animation in `HeaderLogo` whenever the page changes since, as you say, every page renders *some* `Infofield` component.

Comment: That's pretty much what I'm trying to achieve Drew. `HeaderLogo` got in `h1` CSS class animation. In my non-react version, every time html page changes (when clicking on menu item from navigation) logo animation re-starts. I'm looking for a way to mimick this behaviour in my React version of website - as logo is now separate component and has no impulse to restart the animation. I figured synchronizing it with `Infofield` would do, as it re-renders in the exact moment.

Comment: Jeez I'm sorry, the link directs to a different page. One moment. For some unknown reason my server redirects to a different address.

Comment: Would it be too much to ask for a *running* codesandbox demo of your code as well, something we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: No of course not, in on it now. Never used sandbox before, just give me a while please. Very sorry for confusion.

Comment: No worries, I'm pretty patient. If you've hosted your repo in github you can directly import the entire project into codesandbox, just FYI.

Comment: hope this work: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/bckash/code-learning.uk , also link to github public repo : https://github.com/bckash/code-learning.uk

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I totally meant a sandbox with your React code in it.

Comment: no problem. react component: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/bckash/learning-curve-nav-component- , github:  https://github.com/bckash/learning-curve-nav-component-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can gather you simply want to "rerun" an animation in the `HeaderLogo` component when the path changes. Import and use the `useLocation` hook and use the `pathname` value as a React key on the header element with the animation to want to run when it mounts. The idea here is that when the React key changes, React will remount that element.

Example:

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import "./HeaderLogo.css";

const HeaderLogo = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  return (
    <header>
      <h1 key={pathname} className="head-main">
        learning curve
      </h1>
    </header>
  );
};

export default HeaderLogo;
```

[image: Edit rendering-component-after-another-distant-component-renders]

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic job for a global state. You can declare a boolean state, i.e `showHeader`, and add conditional rendering to the  tag.
The global state variable `showHeader` will be changed each time you click on a dropdown item, and in the `App` functional component you should listen for a change in this variable. (For example, using Redux, you'll use `useSelector(state=>state.showHeader)` in `App`.

For an example, this is the `App` component with conditional rendering for the `HeaderLogo`. In order for this to be useable, you need to build a Redux store and reducer functions. [Read the official Redux docs for more](https://react-redux.js.org/tutorials/quick-start)

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import HeaderLogo from "./components/HeaderLogo";
import NaviMain from "./components/NaviMain";
import Info from "./pages/Info";
/...
import { UserContext } from "./components/sub-components/UserContext";
   
function App() {
  const showHeader = useSelector(state=>state.showHeader)
  return (
    <Router>
        <div className="App">
          
            {showHeader ? <HeaderLogo /> : null}
            <NaviMain  />

          <Routes>
             <Route path="/Info" element={<Info />} />
             /...           
          </Routes>
          
        </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
    </Router>
```

Comment: He's not asking how to conditional render a component, but how to trigger a full reset of a component when something happens around your application.  Using the `key` prop is the right way to handle these cases https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key. Yes you could use a global store variable and assign it to the key prop, but since he wants to trigger the component reset on route change, using `location` as @Drew Reese suggested is the best approach.